# Trying to connect to mysql but getting a blank screen

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to connect to a remote mysql server locally but whenever I try to run the page, the page is blank.

```
<?php

    $hostname="xx.xx.xx.xxx";// Remote database server Domain name.
    $username="boss";// as specified in the GRANT command at that server.
    $password="TempPass12";// as specified in the GRANT command at that server.
    $dbname="questions";// Database name at the database server.
    $conn = mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Comment: white screen of death: error checking\display are off, turn them on to see the error. at the top of your php page add: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ini_set('html_errors', 0); error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: Have you checked if there is permission for user `boss` to use remote connection? Also check which IP the mysql server is bound to?

Comment: in addition to @Dagon sugesstion..in your if condition do  `if (!$conn || $conn->connect_error)`

Comment: If you turn error-display on like suggested by @Dagon, you will see an error on the `$conn = mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);` statement, since `mysqli()` function doesn't exist. Here use `mysqli_connect()`instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The Problem

This is a "white screen of death," caused by a fatal error. In this case, the error is

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysqli() in /path/to/your/file.php on line ...

You can't do `$conn = mysqli(...);`. That code is an attempt to call a function named `mysqli`, but no such function exists. Thus the "undefined function" error.

## The Solution

What you *want* to do is intantiate the MySQLi class. That means your code needs to be `$conn = new mysqli(...);`, as [explained in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php).

## Food for Thought

As [Dagon said in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41176413/trying-to-connect-to-mysql-but-getting-a-blank-screen/41176444#comment69553356_41176413), you need to turn on error reporting (and be sure to check your logs) to run down errors like this in the future. Also, a good IDE such as PHPStorm (no affiliation) will help you tremendously with catching errors like this.